# Keyboard covering screen inputs on android

Tags: android, flutter

I have created a mobile app for android and iOS. I have an issue with the keyboard covering the input widgets.

[image]

I added the code below as suggested in another post. It didn't work as you can see from the image.

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

To solve it try to wrapping the body of your scaffold with `singleChildScrollView` and make sure it is `column` the child of the `singleChildScrollView`

Comment: body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[